# Angular - How to output a section of application as secondary standalone build

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli, angular5

I've have an Angular 4 (or 5) application with the following structure:

[image]

How can I build a second standalone angular application, so that only a set of Angular components from **documents** directory outputs into a second *dist* directory.

One of the components from documents directory will serve as main view (some others included as imports). The main component will also need **core** services and some shared components and pipes from **shared** directory.

The *App Component* of the primary application has **nav** and **sidebar** components in its template, I'll not need those in secondary build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There's a story here in Angular-CLI site on how to create multiple applications](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps)

So if you look closely at your .angular-cli.json, your app is in an array, so you can easily add a second app, with a second bootstrapModule

```
 "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },

    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main2.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Then instead of using your original AppModule and AppComponent, you can create an App2Module

main2.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { App2Module } from './app/app2.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(App2Module);
```

Then decide which app you want to build

for first app

```
ng serve --app=0
```

or for second app

```
ng serve --app=1
```